# When I pushed my code to GitHub, it gave me the error "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: git, github

I create my GitHub repository, and then I run this command using Git base:

1. `git init`
2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit -m 'my commit'`
4. `git remote add origin git@github.com:myprofile/my-new-project.git`
5. `git push -u -f origin master`

But after running the last command, my project did not push in Git.

It gave me an error:

```
git push -u -f origin master

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I push my project and why do I get this error?

Comment: "permission denied" means what it says. Use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to diagnose why your ssh can't connect to GitHub, or if it can, who GitHub consequently believe you are; then log in to GitHub and see what access you, as whoever they believe you are, has, to that repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: Note that this has very little to do with Git. Git doesn't know anything about authentication. You are basically asking how to use GitHub. But then just read GitHub's instructions.